# Count the vowels of an input?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

Hi I am trying to count the vowels of the input of the form in my HTML using javascript currently with no success.

Here is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='p3-vowels.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
    Phrase: <input type="text" id = "input1" name="CountVowels" value="Put   Phrase Here"><br>
    <input type="button" id = "btn1" value="Check for Vowels">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript

```
function vow(form){
    var a = form.CountVowels.value;
        flag = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        switch (a[i]){
            case 'a'
            case 'e'
            case 'i'
            case 'o'
            case 'u'
                flag++;
                break;
        }
    }
    alert(flag);
}

function init(){
    var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
    button1.onclick = vow;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: form isn't defined in vow when the button gets clicked

Comment: You've asked the same question three times over the span of ~2 weeks. [Q3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536053/need-help-debugging-vowel-counting-js) is a duplicate of [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521073/why-does-this-code-not-only-count-vowels) is a duplicate of [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242377/count-the-vowels-of-an-input). Instead of repeatedly asking the same question, ask for clarification on your original question. In the future, please refrain from doing this. (This is not the first instance on which you've repeatedly asked the same question.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option to the other answers is to use a regular expression.  This is not necessarily easier to understand, or particularly efficient, but I'm giving it as an alternative.  (It also continues to prove the proverb: give a 100 programmers a problem to solve and you'll get 100 solutions)

The following expression used in javascript will match all the vowels, and you can use the returning array to see how many there are...

```
/[aeiou]/ig
```

The `i` makes it case insensitive, and the `g` means global so it will pick up multiple times.

Here is it in action...

```js
function vow(form){
  var a = form.CountVowels.value;
  var matches = a.match(/[aeiou]/ig);
  var flag = 0;
  if (matches != null)
    flag = matches.length;
  alert(flag);
}

function init(){
  var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
  button1.onclick = function() { vow(document.getElementById("myform")); }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="demo_form.asp">
  Phrase: <input type="text" id = "input1" name="CountVowels" value="Put   Phrase Here"><br>
  <input type="button" id = "btn1" value="Check for Vowels">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your switch statement with

```
if(vowels.indexof(a[i]) > -1)
```

So

```
function vow(form){
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    var a = form.CountVowels.value;
        flag = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
       if(vowels.indexof(a[i]) > -1){
        flag++;
       }
    }
    alert(flag);
}
```

If you want to stick with the switch statement, you can, but you were missing colons ':'

```
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                flag++;
                break;
```

The first method is simpler as you are basically checking if the letter exists in the vowel array.

Comment: Since he doesn't have `break` between the cases, it falls through. He desn't need to repeat the code in each case.

Comment: Would my code look like this 

    function vow(form){
     var a = form.CountVowels.value;
      flag = 0;

     var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']; 
     if(vowels.indexof(a[i]) > -1){
        flag++;
    }
           }
     }
     alert(flag);
    }

    function init(){
     var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
     button1.onclick = vow;
    }

    window.onload = init;

Comment: @joeygmurf, I have updated the first code snippet. That is how your code should look like.

Comment: If the user typed "HELLO WORLD"  how many vowels would it find?

Comment: Still no luck, pressing the button doesn't do anything, is there an error somewhere else in my code??

Answer (score 1):

The `vow` function expects the form as a parameter, but you're not passing it. Give your form an ID so you can look it up and pass it.

```
button1.onclick = function() {
    vow(document.getElementById('demo_form'));
};
```

```js
function vow(form) {
  var a = form.CountVowels.value;
  flag = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    switch (a[i]) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      flag++;
      break;
    }
  }
  alert(flag);
}

function init() {
    var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
    button1.onclick = function() {
      vow(document.getElementById('demo_form'));
    };
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" id="demo_form">
  Phrase:
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="CountVowels" placeholder="Put   Phrase Here">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Check for Vowels">
</form>
```

You were also missing the `:` character after each `case` statement.

Comment: Good point. Such an elementary mistake on my part. He was missing colons!! :)

Comment: `vow(document.getElementById('demo_form');` typo - missing closing bracket

Comment: Okay I tried this and now the page actually does return a value but it is possible to make it so it works for both upper and lower case?

Comment: `switch (a[i].toLowerCase())` or add the uppercase letters to the `switch` cases.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of providing a more readable and concise solution, you can think of counting vowels as a reduction of characters to a single number.

We can do this by reducing the input string to a count of vowels as so:

```
var countVowels = function countVowels(input) {
    return input.split('').reduce(function (a, c) {
       return a + ('aeiou'.indexOf(c) > -1);
    }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the other answers, I think this is **The Simplest Solution**

One line of code and case insensitive. It splits the string at vowels and returns the array length. Why make it more complicated with loops and switch statements?

**update:**
I really like freefaller's solution using match(), which is equal in simplicity. The solution here has a slight edge in that it has wider browser support. Would be interesting to know if there's any speed advantage between the methods.

**Solution:**

```
var vowels = text.split(/[aeiou]/gi).length - 1;
```

**Run code snippet to test:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
  <h1>Vowel Counter Demo</h1>
  
    Count:<span id="count">0</span>
    <p>
    <input onKeyup="update(this.value)" placeholder="Type some text here" style="width:100%"> 
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function update( text ) {
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = vowels(text);  
        }
        
        function vowels( text ) {
            return text.split(/[aeiou]/gi).length - 1;
  
        }
        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You're missing colons after each case statement. I.e., it should be

`case 'a':
 case 'b':` etc.

not

```
case 'a'
case 'b'
```

2) You seem to be assuming that your click event will pass the form that the button is in to the function `vow`. It doesn't.

Just change this:

```
function vow(form){
    var a = form.CountVowels.value;
```

To:

```
function vow(){
    var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
```

Also, you should really be programming with your Console window open to see JS errors. You would have seen both of those issues.